# Rails querying with an array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby-on-rails-4, filter

so in my controller i made a page which shows only the group_pages(the scaffold) in which the array @group_post_users contain the current user so:

```
def my_group
  @group_pages = GroupPage.all
  @group_pages.each do |group_page|    
    @group_page_users = group_page.page_users.split(',')
    @group_page_users.push(group_page.user.email)

    @mg_users = User.find_by_email(@group_page_users)
    @gg_users = User.where(:email => @group_page_users)

    group_page.super_uses = @gg_users
    @g_pages = GroupPage.where(:super_uses => @selected_posts.map(&:id))

  end
end
```

now i have an array of users for a group_page in @group_page_users and i only want to show the group pages which contain the current user inside the @group_page

basically i want something like this :

```
@g_pages = GroupPage.where(:super_uses => current_user.email)
```

Comment: i cant get your question

Comment: your code is quite confusing. I attempted to clean up the formatting but I'm not even sure I got it right. Why is `@group_page_users` an instance attribute when you completely overwrite it each iteration? What do you perceive is the difference between the two lines where you assign `@mg_users` and `@gg_users?` All the work you do in the each loop is undone and you end up with only the last iterations values. It's completely unclear what you WANT to do.

Comment: @g_pages = GroupPage.where(:super_uses => current_user.email)
I want something like this

Comment: @jaydel  please read the above comment